# Twitter Bootstrap Tooltips

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have the following code that is dynamically created on the server side:

```
foreach($pages as $key => $value)
{   
$link = path_get($value['tid'], $value['nid']) ;
$pages[$key]['title'] = "<a href='".$link."' target='blank'>".$value['title'].($value['nid']==1?' (Accueil)':'')."</a>" ;
$pages[$key]['date_post'] = sql_to_datetime($value['date_post']) ;

$edit = "<a href='".url()."admin/page/edit/a/nid/".$value['nid']."' data-toggle='tooltip' title data-original-title='Default tooltip' >".IMG_EDIT."</a> " ; 
$delete = "<a href='".url()."admin/page/index/a/action/delete/nid/".$value['nid']."' data-toggle='tooltip' title data-original-title='Default tooltip' class='delete-element'>".IMG_DELETE."</a> " ; 

$pages[$key]['actions'] = $edit.(user_has_access_menu("page.delete")?$delete:'') ;
}
```

I would like to show a tooltip for each **edit** and **delete** button, but it doesn't display anything.please help

Thanks

Comment: functions.....where? I am able to see your variables.

Comment: please update your full code,then only we can help you

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use title="blabla", data-original-title will be generated by the tooltip function.